# jQuery how to make click handler always reference the parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

Let's say I have a simple parent and child nodes like this:

```
<div id="parent">
    <span id="child">Test</span>
<div>
```

And I have a jQuery click handler like this:

```
$('#parent').click(function (e) {
   alert(e.target.id);
});
```

If I click on the text span, I will get alert 'child'. If I click outside the span but within the parent div, I get alert 'parent'.

What do I need to do, if I want the behavior to change to: If I click anywhere within the parent div, whether it's on the text span or not, I want e.target to be referenced to the parent, and thus get alert of 'parent'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use the `this` keyword (`this.id`) or read the `currentTarget` property of the `event` object, ie. `e.currentTarget.id`.